# Proof that sesquilinear form in is coercive

Tags: sobolev-spaces

> Define $\mathbb{W} = H_{0}^{1}(-1,1) \times H_{0}^{1}(-1,1)$, where $u \in H_{0}^{1}(-1,1)$ if $u,u^{\prime} \in L^{2}(-1,1)$ and $u(-1) = u(1) = 0$. Consider the sesquilinear form $a: \mathbb{W} \times \mathbb{W} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by
> $$
> a((u,v),(w,z)) = \int_{-1}^{1}u^{\prime}\overline{w}^{\prime}dx + \int_{-1}^{1}v^{\prime}\overline{z}^{\prime}dx + \int_{-1}^{1}u\overline{z}dx + \int_{-1}^{1}v\overline{w}dx 
> $$
> for $(u,v),(w,z) \in \mathbb{W}$. I want to show that $a$ is coercive, that is, there is $C > 0$ such that

$$
\text{Re}~a((u,v),(u,v)) \geq C \|(u,v)\|_{W}^{2}, \ \ \forall (u,v) \in \mathbb{W}.
$$

Where $\|(u,v)\|_{W} = \|u\|_{H_{0}^{1}} + \|v\|_{H_{0}^{1}}$, such that $\|u\|_{H_{0}^{1}} = \|u^{\prime}\|_{L^{2}}^{2} + \|u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}  $

Let $(u,v) \in \mathbb{W}$ and
$$
a((u,v),(u,v)) = \int_{-1}^{1}|u^{\prime}|^{2}dx + \int_{-1}^{1}|v^{\prime}|^{2}dx + \int_{-1}^{1}u\overline{v}dx + \int_{-1}^{1}v\overline{u}dx 
$$
But
$$
 \int_{-1}^{1}u\overline{v}dx + \int_{-1}^{1}v\overline{u}dx = 2\text{Re}\int_{-1}^{1}u\overline{v}dx
$$
Then, by Poincaré’s inequality
$$
a((u,v),(u,v)) = \|u^{\prime}\|_{L^{2}}^2 + \|v^{\prime}\|_{L^{2}}^2 +  2\text{Re}\int_{-1}^{1}u\overline{v}dx \geq 2^{-3/2}\|u\|_{L^{2}(-1,1)}^2 + 2^{-3/2}\|v\|_{L^{2}(-1,1)}^2 + 2\text{Re}\int_{-1}^{1}u\overline{v}dx
$$
I know that
$$
0 \leq (\|u\|_{L^{2}} - \|v\|_{L^{2}})^{2} = 
(\|u\|_{L^{2}}^2 + \|v\|_{L^{2}}^2) - 2\|u\|_{L^{2}} \|v\|_{L^{2}}
$$
Then
$$
2\text{Re}\int_{-1}^{1}u\overline{v}dx \leq 2\bigg|\int_{-1}^{1}u\overline{v}dx \bigg| \leq  2\|u\|_{L^{2}} \|v\|_{L^{2}} \leq \|u\|_{L^{2}}^2 + \|v\|_{L^{2}}^2 
$$

But I need a contrary inequality and not the one above. Help me, please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first eigenvalue of the second derivative with Dirichlet b.c. on $(-1,1)$ is $\pi^2/4$ (with eigenfunction $\cos \frac{\pi x}{2}$) and then Poincare' inequality with optimal constant is $\|u\|_2^2 \leq \frac{4}{\pi^2}\|u'\|_2^2$. It follows that
$$2| Re \int_{-1}^1 u\bar v | \leq 2\|u\|_2\|v\|_2 \leq \|u\|_2^2+\|v\|_2^2\leq \frac{4}{\pi^2}(\|u'\|_2^2+\|v'\|_2^2)$$ which gives $C \geq 1-4/\pi^2$, using on $W$ the norm $\|(u,v)\|^2_W=\|u'\|_2^2+\|v'\|_2^2$.

Comment: how did you go about finding this constant $\pi^{2}/4$?

Comment: The minimum of $\|u'\|_2^2/\|u\|_2^2$ is the first eigenvalue of the second derivative.

Comment: I want to show that there is a constant $C < 1$ such that
$
\|u\|_{L^{2}(-1,1)} \leq C \|u^{\prime}\|_{L^{2}(-1,1)}
$ then C is minimum of $\|u\|^{2} / \|u^{\prime}\|^{2}$.

Comment: I'm not able to understand why taking $C \geq 1 - 4/\pi^{2}$ concludes.

Comment: This is true only if $2\text{Re}\int_{-1}^{1}uvdx \geq 0$

Comment: $C \|(u,v)\|^2_W = \bigg(1-4/\pi^2 \bigg) \|(u,v)\|^2_W = \|(u,v)\|^2_W - 2| Re \int_{-1}^1 u\bar v | $.

Comment: does not conclude

Comment: The first eigenvalue $\lambda=\pi^2/4$ is the minimum  of $\|u'\|_2^2/\|u\|_2^2$ and so $\|u\|_2^2 \leq 4/\pi^2\|u'\|_2^2$. Then $$Re a((u,v),(u,v)) \geq \|u'\|_2^2+\|v'\|_2^2-2|Re \int u\bar v| \geq (1-4/\pi^2)( \|u'\|_2^2+\|v'\|_2^2)).$$

Comment: Thank you Very munch.